# Does Spring Cloud Contract support JavaScript and JMS?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I want to start using the framework Spring Cloud Contract for contract testing. But does Spring Cloud Contract support JavaScript and JMS?

I haven't found any information about this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "support of JavaScript" means? We do support JMS either via spring-integration or Apache Camel.

Comment: We will try to use SpringCloudContract in a microService architecture where we have both FrontEnd and BackEnd components. The FrontEnd components is written in JavaScript. So we want to use SpringCloudContract for all our components to do our contract testing. We use Java, JavaScript, REST, JMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>As for the `JMS`, we do support it either via `spring-integration` or `Apache Camel`. You can also write your own `JMS` support. It's enough to register a couple of beans.</s>

<s>As for Javascript and non-jvm languages. There's no out of the box support but we have a process for that. The workflow is described here (in those cases the consumer is a Java app but in the next section I'll describe how the flow would differ) - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_common_repo_with_contracts or https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_step_by_step_guide_to_cdc. We will try to obviously simplify the process but currently there's a bunch of manual tasks to be done (not very tedious though).</s>

<s>The consumer can very easily download and run the stubs. Just clone https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/stub-runner-boot, build it and push the fat jar to your Nexus/Artifactory. This application will be used by the consumers to automatically download stubs and run them locally. As a consumer you can then call `java -jar stub-runner-boot --stubrunner.ids="com.example.groupid:artifactid:classifier:version:8090" --stubrunner.repositoryRoot="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local"` . That way the application will start, download the provided jar with stubs from the given address where your artifactory is. Now your front end application can call the stubs of the producer at `localhost:8090`.</s>

<s>Of course we will try to simplify the cloning and pushing process (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/37) etc.  but for now you have to do those 2 steps manually.</s>

UPDATE:

With this article https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world we're presenting a way how to work in a polyglot environment. It's enough to use the provided docker images to run contract tests against a running application and to run the stub runners too.

Comment: I've updated this answer with a link to the blog where we describe how we do support the flow for non jvm languages